# Sharepoint 2013 error when hosting site in IIS

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

I have a custom web service, which is used to execute a workflow in Sharepoint 2013. Here is part of the code, which works pretty well when I run the web service in VS.

```
WorkflowSubscription workflowSubscription = 
  workflowManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService().GetSubscription(new 
    Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.SPWorkflowId));

Dictionary<string, object> payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
payload.Add("approvers", assignedTopo);
payload.Add("approversbn", assignedTo);
payload.Add("approversgd", assignedTogd);

worfklowService.StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSubscription, 
  Convert.ToInt32(currentFileInSP.ListItemAllFields["ID"]), payload);

context.ExecuteQuery();
enter code here
```

After publishing the web service to IIS the workflow started to show error messages. In English something like this "The operation is prohibited, because it exceeds the threshold value of the list view, set by admin". The exact message in Russian is "Операция, попытка выполнить которую осуществляется, запрещена, поскольку она превышает пороговое значение представления списка, принудительно установленное администратором." How can IIS influence SharePoint like this? Could the problem be related to encoding? Here is the screenshot of error message:

[image]

By the way, in the same web service I upload file to SharePoint. This part of code is working fine even in IIS.